# Get value, type and names of properties and fields of a class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

There are a ton of topics similar to this question, however, some of them are only for fields, the others are properties. I need a code snippet that retrieves *values*, *types*, and *names* of a class’s *properties and fields*. The following code works for *only properties*, not also for *fields*. I need *both* at once.

@Edit; <s>If possible without loop, total number of properties and fields can be retrieved.</s>

@Edit2; I think it can be done with `.Count` property.

What I’ve tried,

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item))
{
    string name = descriptor.Name;              // Name
    object value = descriptor.GetValue(item);   // Value
    var type = descriptor.PropertyType;         // Type
    Console.WriteLine($"{name}={value}={type}");
}
```

It outputs for the example class as,

```
humidity=abcd=System.String
temperature=123,12=System.Double
pressure=99=System.Int32
```

Example class,

```
class ExampClass
{
    public string testFieldJustField = "so";
    public string humidity { get; private set; }
    public double temperature { get; private set; }
    public int pressure { get; private set; }

    public ExampClass(string h, double t, int p)
    {
        humidity = h;
        temperature = t;
        pressure = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [GetMembers(BindingFlags)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmembers?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetMembers_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) and specify the flags for the members (fields, properties, and methods) that you want.

Comment: @JohnWu I don’t think your approach works since “the type” yields  `System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo` and similar for property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *query* without (explicit) loops, you can try *Linq*:

First we want all `public` *instance* properties, which *can be read* and are *not indexers*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  var item = new ExampClass("abcd", 123.12, 99);

  ...

  //TODO: Specify with a help of BindingFlags which properties do you want
  var props = item
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(pi => pi.CanRead)                      // can be read
    .Where(pi => !pi.GetIndexParameters().Any())  // not an indexer
    .Select(pi => new {
      name = pi.Name,
      value = pi.GetValue(pi.GetGetMethod().IsStatic ? null : item),
      type = pi.PropertyType,
      kind = "property",                          
    });
```

Second we want all `public` *instance* fields:

```
  //TODO: Specify with a help of BindingFlags which fields do you want
  var fields = item
    .GetType()
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(fi => new {
      name = fi.Name,
      value = fi.GetValue(fi.IsStatic ? null : item),
      type = fi.FieldType,
      kind = "field",
    });
```

Finally, we can *combine* both queries with a help of `Concat`:

```
  var result = props
    .Concat(fields)
    .OrderBy(record => record.name) // let's have results ordered
    .Select(record => $"{record.name}={record.value}={record.type}");

  // string.Join in order to avoid loops
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));

  // If you want total numbers put Count() 
  int total = props
    .Concat(fields)
    .Count();

  Console.WriteLine(total);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  humidity=abcd=System.String
  pressure=99=System.Int32 
  temperature=123,12=System.Double
  testFieldJustField=so=System.String 
  4
```